# How to setup a headless Raspberry Pi for use with SSH now that adding /boot/ssh blank file is no longer enough?

Tags: ssh, headless, windows

In the past, adding an empty file `/boot/ssh` from Windows (because boot is a FAT32 partition if I remember correctly) was enough to setup a fresh RaspiOS install for a headless RPi without screen.

Now it seems that even if `/boot/ssh` is created, it is no longer possible to ssh with Putty on `pi@raspberrypi.local` with password `raspberry`.

**Question: how to enable SSH with password on a fresh headless RPi install, with Windows?**

How to activate `login=pi` `password=raspberry` without having a screen monitor?

PS: I see the reason why they disabled the legacy way (security), but the current design is poor. We should be able to setup a headless RPi without using a monitor.

Comment: `We should be able to setup a headless RPi without using a monitor.` still possible. Use pi-imager to write and set up PiOS. Refer to e.g. the official docs

Comment: Try reading the documentation for [Raspberry Pi Imager](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/getting-started.html#using-raspberry-pi-imager) but is it REALLY that hard to use a screen & keyboard for initial setup? "the current design" is how every other Linux OS is setup.

Comment: Why are you trying a fresh install? Just update your current install.

Comment: @Milliways No, in my case I'm often preparing new distributions for an embedded project (to be distributed), and when I release new ready-to-use ISO distributions, I want to start from a clean fresh RaspiOS.

Comment: `is it REALLY that hard to use a screen & keyboard for initial setup`: Yes as I'm often working during trips, and I only have backpack + laptop + a few RPi. Also, it contradicts the whole spirit of a headless RPi, if you have to use a screen to set it up...

Comment: @Dirk, Is it really mpossible with a simple setup like: write `2023-05-03-raspios-bullseye-armhf-lite.img` to micro SD card, create a `ssh` empty file + do something else to authorize `pi / raspberry` login/password?

Comment: With pi-imager you just install the image and use the advanced options to set up user, networking (wifi, etc\), ssh, etc. No need for any manual actions afterward. As I said: read the official docs.

Comment: I just used pi-imager last week to do this - got ssh (and VNC) all working and never once plugged a keyboard or mouse into the pi  

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want to do this without normal setup follow the instructions:-

[Configuring a User](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/configuration.html#configuring-a-user)

which is part of the documented process for
[Setting up a Headless Raspberry Pi](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/configuration.html#setting-up-a-headless-raspberry-pi):

> IMPORTANT
> If you are installing Raspberry Pi OS, and intend to run it headless, you will need to create a new user account. Since you will not be able to create the user account using the first-boot wizard as it requires both a monitor and a keyboard, you MUST add a userconf.txt file to the boot folder to create a user on first boot or configure the OS with a user account using the Advanced Menu in the Raspberry Pi Imager.

> The imager has options to to this at imaging stage.

This was also explained in the blog [Raspberry Pi Bullseye Update](https://www.raspberrypi.com/news/raspberry-pi-bullseye-update-april-2022/)   of 7th Apr 2022 which announced the security change.

If you search the internet you will even find ready made `userconf.txt` files to set pi:raspberry

Comment: Thanks a lot @Milliways! This `userconf.txt` file seems to be the solution for my use case! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

> with Windows? ... it contradicts the whole spirit of a headless RPi, if you have to use a screen to set it up...

Then in the spirit of such install a linux VM on your windows box so you can access the primary ext4 partition with the OS root filesystem on it, and it is as simple as:

```
export mountpoint=/mnt/sd # Or wherever it's mounted.
ln -s /lib/systemd/system/ssh.service ${mountpoint}/etc/systemd/system/default.target.wants/
```

It may be worth noting that the first path given to `ln -s` is recorded in the second path, so at this it will point to the `ssh.service` in the running system (if that path exists, which it will for most debian derived distros at least), but when the card is put back in the Pi will point to the one on the card. In any case, make sure the link exists in `${mountpoint}/etc/systemd/...`.

Then:

```
cd ${mountpoint}/etc/ssh/
rm -f ssh_host_*key*
ssh-keygen -A 
cd ~
```

Alternately, you can enable `sshswitch` instead of `ssh`, then add a `/boot/ssh` and that will work to do much the same thing.

Comment: Thanks a lot @goldilocks. Yes this will probably work. It is just sad that all these extra steps are needed to setup a simple headless RPi. It was too good before :) when just creating `/boot/ssh` empty file was enough :)